Detecting Largest volume in Pine script
I want to be able to detect if today's volume is the largest in the lifetime of a stock. How to do this. Currently, I manually set the lookback period to do screening. But I want it to be dynamic
indicator("Max Volume", overlay = true)
lookback = input(1000, 'Lookback input')
flag = (volume == ta.highest(volume, lookback))
plotchar(flag, location = location.abovebar, color = color.fuchsia, size = size.normal)


You can use a var variable and update its value as you go. Please note that, this will not be the true ATH. It will be the ATH of your chart's timeframe. The true ATH cannot be obtained.
var ath_vol = volume

if (volume > ath_vol)
    ath_vol := volume

